# How can I create a PDF document from MySQL table data PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdf

I want to get data from the MySQL data base and make and create a PDF file of the data.

Here is my code, it saving the PDF file but it can not be opened.

```
<?php  
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'xxxx';
$db = 'db';

$link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Can not connect." . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die("Can not connect.");

$query = "SELECT childID,sex from child ";  

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 

    while(mysql_fetch_array($result))  
    {  
        header("Content-length: $size"); 
        header("Content-type: $type"); 
        header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$username-$description.pdf"); 
    } 
    echo $content;
    mysql_close($link); 
    exit; 
?>
```

Comment: You can't do that way. Use TCPDF http://www.tcpdf.org/ or FPDF http://www.fpdf.org/ library

Comment: try FPDF: http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: one of the best tools is wkhtmltopdf, it uses web kit to render the html and from that to generate the pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use any of the following php scripts to generate dynamic PDF documents

FPDF: http://www.fpdf.org/

TCPDF: http://www.tcpdf.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMPDF. for more details look at the :

http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/downloads/detail?name=dompdf_0-6-0_beta3.zip